# How do I challenge a question marked as "duplicate" that isn't actually a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So this question was recently asked: "[Any Recent News on a Foundation (Asimov) Series of Movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50018/any-recent-news-on-a-foundation-asimov-series-of-movies)"

It's been marked as a duplicate of this previous question: "[Have any movies been based on Isaac Asimov's Foundation Series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4532/have-any-movies-been-based-on-isaac-asimovs-foundation-series)"

The previous question was asked 3.5 years ago, and the most recent answer there is about 2 years old. The new question is asking about *recent* news. There is no recent news in that previous question. There *can't* be recent news there - it's over 2 years old.

The note about the duplication says:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question

But, those old answers *can't* fully address a question about recent news.

And, I don't know how to "un"-mark that question as a duplicate for the asker.

Comment: [When you reach 3k rep, you can cast close and reopen votes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).  In the meantime, here on Meta is the right place to ask for clarifications (and possibly get it reopened).

Comment: That said, I agree with closing it as a duplicate.  Questions have no time limit on them - and the accepted answer links directly to one of the best places to find out the most recent information.  (Well, it does now; the link had changed slightly, I just fixed it)

Comment: Thanks for explaining about closing/opening votes.

Comment: So how does a two-year question answer a current question about recent news? This confuses me. There's no information in that thread more recent than May 2012. How is that considered an answer to a question about *recent* news?

Comment: @Algernon_Asimov I think the main issue here is that this site really isn't geared towards "What's the most recent news". StackExchange sites try to become repositories of knowledge. If your question becomes meaningless in six months, it's not a good fit for the site. A better way to do it is to update the older question with updated information.

Comment: related on the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/147247

Answer (score 13):

As Avner [says in the comments](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3377/how-do-i-challenge-a-question-marked-as-duplicate-that-isnt-actually-a-duplic?rq=1#comment10486_3377):

> I think the main issue here is that this site really isn't geared towards "What's the most recent news". StackExchange sites try to become repositories of knowledge. If your question becomes meaningless in six months, it's not a good fit for the site. A better way to do it is to update the older question with updated information.

We used to have a close reason of 'Too localised' but this has vanished. IF it had not I would have closed it with that reasoning.

As it stands it's either 'Too Broad' (expected to be valid for all time, and cannot be). Or it is 'Primarily Opinion based' (what is 'current'?)

As it stands I may add another 'off-topic' category for 'News, and current events.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: Upvoted for everything except that last line.

Comment: @keen to the bat cave? I mean <strike>chat room</strike> meta.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to cover everything here.  I was the one who closed the question, since the old question is perfectly capable of addressing 'recent' news.

> The previous question was asked 3.5 years ago, and the most recent answer there is about 2 years old. The new question is asking about recent news. There is no recent news in that previous question. There can't be recent news there - it's over 2 years old.

Questions and answers can and should [be edited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to be updated if they're out of date.  We even have [a bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) reason devoted to 'current answers are outdated' to help encourage this.

> And, I don't know how to "un"-mark that question as a duplicate for the asker.

When you have enough reputation, you can [vote to reopen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) closed/on-hold questions.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all that. But, how do people know to update a 3-year-old question? The default sorting algorithm here prioritises questions which have had some recent action: this particular question has had no changes in 2 years. No one will ever see it, to know that it needs updating.

Comment: They find old questions by searching? Long-time users remember the question? Someone notices that the answers are outdated and offers a bounty? All have resulted in older questions getting updated answers.